Shrink an object with respect to global coordinates
I have checked the following site but cannot understand it well.
How to set child object world scale using python?
I am having trouble executing the Script drawn here.

The goal is a Script that shrinks the object in a "certain axis".　
We want to reduce the size in "global" coordinates.
Thank you.
def scale_object(obj, axis, factor):
    # Get the world matrix of the target object
    world_matrix = obj.matrix_world.copy()

    # Set the scaling axis based on the input axis
    if axis == 'X':
        scale_axis = (1, 0, 0)
    elif axis == 'Y':
        scale_axis = (0, 1, 0)
    elif axis == 'Z':
        scale_axis = (0, 0, 1)
    else:
        print("Invalid axis. Please specify 'X', 'Y', or 'Z'.")
        return

    # Create a scaling matrix based on the specified axis
    scale_matrix = Matrix.Scale(factor, 4, scale_axis)

    # Apply the scaling matrix to the object's world matrix
    obj.matrix_world = scale_matrix @ world_matrix


So, you want to change the parent's scale value and keep the child's shape?

That is not the case. Sorry if my interpretation is wrong, but I think the global coordinates are always constant.
That is, it is an axis that does not depend on the rotation of the object.
I want to change the scale of the object in that constant direction.thanks.

Directly change the mesh vertex coordinates via a scale factor
import bpy, bmesh
from mathutils import Vector

def catch(func):
    def wrapper(*arg, **kw):
        try:
            return func(*arg, **kw)
        except Exception as e:
            print(str(e))
    return wrapper

@ catch
def restore_mode():
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode=restore_mode.mode)

@ catch
def to_mode(mode):
    restore_mode.mode = bpy.context.object.mode
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode=mode)


def scale_mesh_on_world_axis(ob, fac3, origin=None):
    if hasattr(ob, "type") and ob.type == "MESH": pass
    else:
        print("MESH object only")
        return

    if ob.mode != "EDIT":
        to_mode("EDIT")

    if origin is None:
        origin = ob.location.copy()
    else:
        origin = Vector(origin)

    mat = ob.matrix_world
    mat_inv = mat.inverted()
    fac3 = Vector(fac3)
    bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(ob.data)

    for v in bm.verts:
        vec = mat @ v.co - origin
        v.co[:] = mat_inv @ (origin + vec * fac3)

    ob.data.update()
    restore_mode()


# Scale mesh on world axis x
scale_mesh_on_world_axis(bpy.context.object, (2, 1, 1))


Thanks! I will research the script!

I still found that it is not feasible without appling the rotation!

As an alternative, we have created a Script that edits the mesh directly.

Hmm..I noticed some mistake in my script.. It requires direct editing of the mesh coordinates to accomplish what you want.

I'm assuming object mode, which is not a very smart way to do it,
At any rate, we have created a method to shrink the mesh itself in the global direction.
import bpy
import bmesh
from mathutils import Matrix, Vector

def scale_mesh_global(obj_name, direction, factor):
    # Get the object
    obj = bpy.data.objects[obj_name]
    
    # Ensure the object is a mesh
    if obj.type != 'MESH':
        raise ValueError(f"Object {obj_name} is not a mesh.")
    
    # Switch to edit mode
    bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = obj
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
    
    # Create a BMesh and get the mesh data in edit mode
    bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(obj.data)
    
    # Get the world matrix and its inverse
    world_matrix = obj.matrix_world
    world_matrix_inv = world_matrix.inverted()
    
    # Set the scaling vector based on the direction
    scale_vector = Vector((1, 1, 1))
    direction = direction.upper()
    if direction == 'X':
        scale_vector.x = factor
    elif direction == 'Y':
        scale_vector.y = factor
    elif direction == 'Z':
        scale_vector.z = factor
    else:
        raise ValueError("Direction must be 'X', 'Y', or 'Z'.")
    
    # Get the object's location
    obj_location = obj.location
    
    # Scale all vertices
    for vert in bm.verts:
        # Convert to global coordinates
        global_coord = world_matrix @ vert.co
        # Scale relative to the object's location
        offset_coord = global_coord - obj_location
        scaled_offset_coord = offset_coord * scale_vector
        scaled_global_coord = scaled_offset_coord + obj_location
        # Convert back to local coordinates
        vert.co = world_matrix_inv @ scaled_global_coord
    
    # Update the mesh and return to object mode
    bmesh.update_edit_mesh(obj.data)
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')

# Example usage
scale_mesh_global('Cube', 'Z', 0.5)  # Scale the 'Cube' object by 0.5 along the Z direction


